# Can small growth functions of big-0 be considered larger?

Tags: math, big-o

Can smaller growth functions such as f(n)= 45n+3 be considered o(2^n) as well as o(n)

Comment: I think `f(n)` is only `o(2^n)`, but not `o(n)`.  However, it is `O(n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `f(n) = o(g(n)` and `g(n) = o(h(n))` then `f(n) = o(h(n))`.

Proof: There are different definitions for `o` but one involves limits: `f(n) = o(g(n))` can be defined to mean that `lim f(n)/g(n) -> 0` as `n -> +inf`. Suppose `f(n) = o(g(n))` and `g(n) = o(h(n))`. Then `lim f(n)/g(n) -> 0` and `lim g(n)/h(n) -> 0`. We can find `lim f(n)/h(n)` by multiplying top and bottom by `g(n)` to get `lim f(n)/h(n) x g(n)/g(n)`. We can rearrange this to get `lim f(n)/g(n) x g(n)/h(n)`. The limit of a product is the product of limits when the limits exist, and both of ours do: `lim f(n)/g(n)  x g(n)/h(n) = 0 x 0 = 0`. So we have `lim f(n)/h(n) = 0`, or `f(n) = o(h(n))`, as required.

As pointed out, it is not the case that `45n + 3 = o(n)` as in your example. Indeed, `lim (45n + 3)/n = 45`, not `0`, as would be required.

There is another definition of `o` which I prefer: `f(n) = o(g(n))` iff `for all c > 0 there exists n0 such that for n > n0, f(n) < cg(n)`. This shows the relationship to `O` better. The proof of transitivity is as follows:

Proof. Assume `f(n) = o(g(n))` and `g(n) = o(h(n))`. Then for all `c > 0` there exists `n0` such that `f(n) < cg(n)` for all `n > n0` and for all `c' > 0` there exists `n0'` such that `g(n) < c'h(n)` for all `n > n0'`. Let `n0'' = max(n0, n0')` and `c'' = cc'`. Then `f(n) < cg(n) < cc'h(n) = c''h(n)` for all `n > n''`; thus, `f(n) = o(h(n))`, as desired.

Comment: One bit of pedantry... `o(g(n))` and `O(g(n))` are sets of functions with certain properties.  Therefore it is more correct to say `f(n)∈o(g(n))`, etc.